# show view location at current location + map view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

i have web view in that i am loading list of data

i m  aslo showing my current location . now i want to zoom my view in at my current location.

in map view i m showing many data . my view is showing me zooming location at my last data  location at my last data .

Answer (score 0):

I created a method to move the map to a location:

```
-(void)setMapPosition:(CLLocation *)location animated:(BOOL)ani
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude =  location.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.015;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.015;

    [myMapView setRegion:region animated:ani];

}
```

Show user location:

```
[self setMapPosition:myMapView.userLocation.location animated:YES];
```